# String Interpolation C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

If we can one store the temp_data of a string in a variable and use interpolation on it?

```
var name = "John";

var temp_data = "Hi {name}";

var result_data = $temp_data;
```

If their any possible solution are available other than `string.Format()` and `string.Replace()`

Comment: What do you mean "use interpolation on it" ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but I think you want this: $"Hi {name}"

Comment: How about `var result_data = temp_data.Replace("{name}", name);`?

Comment: Because for me the temp_data will get data from DB

Comment: Interpolation is _compile time_ syntactic sugar for a regular `String.Format`.  You'll need to use that (or some other templating code).

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` if you do not want to use `String.Format` and `String.Replace`

Comment: @AfnanAhmad ok thanks

Comment: Or use C#6 interpolation !

Comment: It's : $"Hi {name}"

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to store the message as an external resource you will need to use string.Format rather than string interpolation, interpolated strings have to exist in their entirety at compile time as string literals.

You will also need to ensure that the number of variables contained in the message match those in the code calling string.format otherwise it will not transpose correctly.

As an example, this is using a resource file;

```
var message = string.Format(Strings.ErrorMessage, value1, value2);
```

Strings.ErrorMessage would contain;

> "This is the error {0} and message {1}"

Comment: @Leogiciel No, because you can't when using an message that is external to the code (db/resource file) as explained in my answer.

Comment: You're right, I definitely misunderstood this poorly-explained use-case. String.Format is then the right solution, +1 kudos.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `$ - string interpolation (C# Reference)`
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score -2):

you can use like this

```
double speedOfLight = 299792.458;
FormattableString message = $"The speed of light is {speedOfLight:N3} km/s.";

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL");
string messageInCurrentCulture = message.ToString();

var specificCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-IN");
string messageInSpecificCulture = message.ToString(specificCulture);

string messageInInvariantCulture = FormattableString.Invariant(message);

Console.WriteLine($"{System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,-10} {messageInCurrentCulture}");
Console.WriteLine($"{specificCulture,-10} {messageInSpecificCulture}");
Console.WriteLine($"{"Invariant",-10} {messageInInvariantCulture}");
```

Answer (score -3):

Using C#6, you can do exactly what you wrote, without the typo :

```
var name = "John";

var temp_data = $"Hi {name}";

var result_data = temp_data;

Console.log(result_data);
```

will return "Hi John" ;)

Comment: Does not answer the question, the message (temp_data) needs to come from a database/external resource and what is the purpose of creating another string (result_data)

Comment: Where do you read something about database/external resource ?? Creating another string is only to keep the question example form......

Comment: See comments below question

Comment: I would also add that your example does not use string interpolation anyway, the value of result_data is "Hi {name")

Comment: Then feel free to post a working example of loading the message from an external resource 'and' using string interpolation

Comment: Right, fixed the typo